# React app not rendering when using .toUpperCase in props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I am coding in react and need to change the book title to upper case.

When I add the code react is not rendering the page, and I get this error in the console. "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toUpperCase')"

When I console log props.author.toUpperCase() it is logging it correctly.

Is there any solution to this?  Thanks in Advance.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDom from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";

const firstBook = {
  img: "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41cvjNsNDaL._SX324_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg",
  title: "The Final Gambit",
  author: "Jennifer Lynn Barnes",
};
const secondBook = {
  img: "https://d30a6s96kk7rhm.cloudfront.net/original/978/152/939/9781529394436.jpg",
  title: "Dune",
  author: "Frank Herbert",
};

function BookList() {
  return (
    <section className="booklist">
      <Book
        img={firstBook.img}
        title={firstBook.title}
        author={firstBook.author}
      />
      <Book
        img={secondBook.img}
        title={secondBook.title}
        author={secondBook.author}
      />
      <Book />
    </section>
  );
}

const Book = (props) => {
  return (
    <article className="book">
      <img src={props.img} alt="bookcover" className="bookcover" />
      <h1>{props.title}</h1>
      <h4>{props.author.toUpperCase()}</h4>
    </article>
  );
};
ReactDom.render(<BookList />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: because the last Book component you called, doesn't have any props and this causes an error

Answer (score 0):

Check out the console log in this sandbox to see what went wrong: https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-rumple-1izckh?file=/src/App.js

The first two `Book` components work fine since they have the author and the title passed from the `BookList` component. However the last Book `<Book />` does not have any props received, and thus `props.author` and `props.title` are undefined